# How can I save an image in GEOTIFF format?

Tags: python, geotiff, google-earth-engine

I'm having some trouble for a project work. I have to calculate NDVI for a specific area of the Apulia region, South Italy, using images from **Sentinel 2 satellite** and **Python language**.

In order to accomplish the task, I thought of dividing the workflow in these steps:

- create a ROI
- take the image collection from the satellite
- export the collection into the RGB bands (B4, B3, B2) in ***GEOTIFF*** format
- export the collection into the NIR band (B8) in ***GEOTIFF*** format
- use the SNAP tool to calculate the NDVI

---

First of all, my first problem is that I must insert my ROI (Geometry.Polygon) inline, otherwise I will have a completely blank image. How could I resolve this and **have a variable "roi" so I can use the filterBounds command?** (The code is shown below)

Then, **how could I export the image as said before?**

---

```
ee.mapclient.centerMap(15.7151226, 41.5049459, 11)
collection = (ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2') 
          .filter(ee.Filter.lt("CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE", 10)) 
          .filterDate('2018-05-01', '2018-10-30')
          .filterBounds(ee.Geometry.Polygon([
              [15.031742, 41.736782], [16.152907, 41.736782], 
              [15.031742, 41.321053], [16.152907, 41.321053]]))
          )
```